# Can't get draft-js Modifier's applyInlineStyle function to apply inline style

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am leveraging the draft-js and react-draft-wysiwyg libraries to create a WYSIWYG editor. I am looking to add some custom options to the toolbar to render the final HTML, such as inline `line-height`. However, I cannot get the [Modifier's](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-modifier#applyinlinestyle) `applyInlineStyle()` function to work properly.

Editor:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ContentState, convertFromHTML, convertFromRaw, convertToRaw, EditorState, Modifier } from "draft-js";
import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";
import draftToHtml from "draftjs-to-html";
import "../node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";

const toolbarOptions = {
  options: ["inline"],
  inline: {
    options: ["bold", "italic", "underline"],
    bold: { className: "rich-text-icon" },
    italic: { className: "rich-text-icon" },
    underline: { className: "rich-text-icon" }
  },
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
      finalHTML: ""
    };
  }

  onEditorStateChange = editorState => {
    const raw = convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent());
    const markup = draftToHtml(raw);
    this.setState({
      editorState,
      finalHTML: markup
    });
    console.log(markup);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="App">
          <Editor
            editorState={this.state.editorState}
            onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
            toolbar={toolbarOptions}
            toolbarCustomButtons={[<ApplyLineHeight />]}
            stripPastedStyles={true}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Custom line height option:

```
class ApplyLineHeight extends Component {
  applyLineHeight = () => {
    const { editorState, onChange } = this.props;
    const contentState = Modifier.applyInlineStyle(editorState.getCurrentContent(), editorState.getSelection(), "line-height: 20px;");
    onChange(EditorState.push(editorState, contentState, "change-inline-style"));
  };

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.applyLineHeight}>Change line height</div>;
  }
}
```

When I follow the example from the [docs](https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/docs) (under "Adding new option to the toolbar"), it works with the `Modifier.replaceText()` function (to replace text) but it does not work when attempting to return line-height. I am returned the same `<p></p>` tags with no inline style applied. What could be causing this function to not render?

Comment: It seems like you are not returning 'handled' after you apply the inline style manually. If you just return 'handled' after `onChange(EditorState.push(editorState, contentState, "change-inline-style"));`, it might fix the issue. Currently, Draft is also handling the same action which might mess things up.

Comment: how did you solve this ?

Comment: any progress with this? i have the same issue

Answer (score 2):

let's see api **Modifier.applyInlineStyle()** first

```
applyInlineStyle(
  contentState: ContentState,
  selectionState: SelectionState,
  inlineStyle: string 
): ContentState
```

The **inlineStyle** should be name defined in **customStyleMap**

The **customStyleMap** is property of **Editor**

just like this

```
import {Editor} from 'draft-js';

const styleMap = {
  'STRIKETHROUGH': {  // STRIKETHROUGH is the one which should be applied to inlineStyle
    textDecoration: 'line-through',
  },
};

class MyEditor extends React.Component {
  // ...
  render() {
    return (
      <Editor
        customStyleMap={styleMap}
        editorState={this.state.editorState}
        ...
      />
    );
  }
}
// The usage should be like this:
// Modifier.applyInlineStyle(xxx, xxx, 'STRIKETHROUGH')
```

Answer (score 0):

**draftjs-to-html** does not convert every inline style,yet it supports a few things like color, background color, font-size, font-family

Firstly define the styles with an individual CSS property:

Eg:

```
const styles = {
    'color-#222833': {
        color: '#222833',
    },
    'color-#005EFF': {
        color: '#005EFF',
    },
    'fontfamily-Montserrat': {
        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
    },
    'fontsize-18px': {
        fontSize: '18px',
    },}
```

Note : use the exact same inline style names

Secondly To add multiple CSS properties at once ,Create an array of custom classes created

Eg:

```
 H2: ['color-#222833', 'fontsize-18px', 'fontfamily-Montserrat', 'BOLD'],
 BODY: ['color-#222833', 'fontsize-15px', 'fontfamily-Montserrat'],
```

Iterate the Array to apply the styles one by one using the RichUtils API

```
import { RichUtils } from 'draft-js';
const UpdateState = ['color#222833','fontsize15px','fontfamilyMontserrat']
            .reduce((state, style)=>RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(state, style)
            , editorState);

onChange(UpdateState);
```

Reference :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/draftjs-to-html

https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/main/examples/draft-0-10-0/color/color.html